AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: OSRSetAxisMappingStrategy
I'm trying to start my project in docker, it was working great, but now something happened and it can't start. It crashes with
AttributeError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: OSRSetAxisMappingStrategy

I searched a lot but have no idea how to make it work. I've tried updating all the libs I have, but no effect whatsoever.
Here's what I use:

Django
Postgis
Docker-compose
Docker

My docker configuration:
FROM python:3.11-buster

# Set work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        binutils \
        libproj-dev \
        gdal-bin \
        libgdal-dev \
        postgresql-client \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \

ENV CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal
ENV C_INCLUDE_PATH=/usr/include/gdal

# Install Poetry
COPY pyproject.toml poetry.lock* ./
RUN pip install poetry && \
    poetry config virtualenvs.create false && \
    poetry install --no-dev

# Copy the application code
COPY . .

# Expose ports
EXPOSE 8000
EXPOSE 8001

# Run the application
ENTRYPOINT ["sh", "-c", "poetry run gunicorn app.wsgi:application --bind 0.0.0.0:8000"]


not sure if this is the answer you're looking for, but I have experienced the same problem today and resolved it by upgrading from python:3.11-buster to python:3.12-bookworm.
This is my updated docker config:
FROM python:3.12-bookworm

# Create and set the directory where the source code is stored.
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Set environment variables. Note language set to en-GB.
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV LANG en_GB.UTF-8
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING utf_8

# Install system packages required by Wagtail, Django and Psycopg2 and PostGIS
RUN apt-get update --yes --quiet && apt-get install --yes --quiet --no-install-recommends \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    gdal-bin \
    libgdal-dev \
    libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libwebp-dev \
    python-dev-is-python3 \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Copy the source code and install dependencies
COPY Pipfile Pipfile.lock /usr/src/app/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install pipenv && pipenv install --system

Note, I also had to swap libmariadbclient-dev to libmariadb-dev-compat libmariadb-dev and python-dev to python-dev-is-python3
Hope this helps.

Wow, thank you, I've changed to 3.12-bookworm and everything is now working!
